# How to extract a selected files from sample.tar.gz file usin gpython script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wannted to extract some selected files from a sample.tar.gz files ( do not need  to be extracted all the files inside sample.tar.gz files ) the file structures are looks like below.

```
sample.tar.gz is the base file, under this base file following files are contained.
 hello_usb.tar.gz
 hello_usb1.tar.gz
 hello_usb2.tar.gz
 world_usb1.tar.gz
 world_usb2.tar.gz
 world_usb3.tar.gz
```

I wanted to extract only "hello_*" files are to be extracted ( while extracting it should create a fiolder name same as the file name for example, while extracting hello_usb.tar.gz file it should create a folder name called as hello_usb.tar.gz/...  )

I have tried with following codes but no luck.

```
tar = tarfile.open("D:\Python34\Testing\sample.tar.gz", "r:gz")
only_names = tar.getnames()
for count in range(len(only_names)):
   print (only_names[count][:9])
   if only_names[count][:9] == "hello_usb":
      tar.extract(only_names[count], path = "D:\Python34\Testing")
      #tar.extractfile(only_names[count])
```

Your help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work.

```
import shutil
import glob
import os

with tarfile.open('D:\Python34\Testing\sample.tar.gz', 'r:gz') as tar:
    tar.extractall()
    os.chdir('sample')
    for arch in glob.glob('hello_*'):
        shutil.unpack_archive(arch, 'D:\Python34\Testing')
```